# Pandavas - Excellent Trekkers

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas

[Pandava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandava)

[Trekking](https://www.google.com/search?q=trekking&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&sca_esv=2ce33e14709b89c1&sxsrf=ACQVn08mtlErNXd8DpxmpJsb8ZHGPWegKQ%3A1711516381893&ei=3aoDZo-ONrGNvr0PndOSkAY&udm=&oq=trekking&gs_lp=EhNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwIgh0cmVra2luZzIKECMYgAQYigUYJzIKECMYgAQYigUYJzIQEAAYgAQYFBiHAhixAxjJAzILEAAYgAQYigUYkgMyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDINEAAYgAQYFBiHAhixAzILEAAYgAQYigUYsQNIrCtQrg1YtSJwAXgAkAEAmAGuAqAB2RCqAQcwLjcuMy4xuAEDyAEA-AEBmAIFoALOBsICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAhAQABiABBiKBRhDGMkDGLADwgIOEAAYgAQYigUYkgMYsAPCAg0QABiABBiKBRhDGLADwgIGEAAYFhgewgILEAAYgAQYigUYhgPCAgUQIRigAcICCBAAGIAEGMkDmAMAiAYBkAYPkgcFMS4zLjGgB9tK&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp)

Can we conclude saying Pandava were excellent trekkers?